# Create funnel plot with residuals using metafor

Tags: metafor

Using metafor in R:
How can you plot residuals on the x-axis of a funnel plot for a model that does not contain any moderators?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not intended, you could override the logical inside `rma` objects that indicates that you have fitted an 'intercept-only' model. To illustrate:

```
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg)
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
funnel(res)
```

So this gives you a standard funnel plot. Now force `int.only` to be `FALSE`. Then you get a funnel plot of the residuals:

```
res$int.only <- FALSE
funnel(res)
```

Another way to do this is to extract the residuals and corresponding variances manually and pass them to the `funnel()` function directly:

```
ei  <- resid(res)
vei <- diag(vcov(res, type="resid"))
funnel(ei, vei, xlab="Residual Value")
```